# Can i specify a listener in kafka to communicate with zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to kafka. i am setting up kafka cluster in openshift and in the process configuring various listeners.
EXT_NETWORK://0.0.0.0:9092
INT_NETWORK://0.0.0.0:9094
INTER_BROKER://0.0.0.0:9095

does kafka uses one of the configured listener to communicate with zookeeper ? if yes how that listener can be configured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listeners are how the **clients** communicate with the **brokers**, and are separate from how Kafka communicates with Zookeeper. For more information see [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-07-01&utm_term=rmoff-devx).